# Define ICommand as async lambda calling async Task, or just async void?

Tags: c#, async-await, icommand

Consider the following two ways of setting an ICommand to perform an asynchronous task (in this case, using `Xamarin.Forms.Command`, but I expect that's not critical):

Scenario 1: setting the command to an async lambda in which you await an `async Task` method:

```
// Command definition
ToggleCheckedCommand = new Command(
    execute: async () => { await ToggleCheckedAsync(); },
    canExecute: () => !IsBusy);

// Method that is executed
private async Task ToggleCheckedAsync()
{
    IsBusy = true;
    await DoWork();
    IsBusy = false;
}
```

Scenario 2: Setting the command to an `async void` method:

```
// Command definition
ToggleCheckedCommand = new Command(
    execute: ToggleCheckedAsync,
    canExecute: () => !IsBusy);

// Method that is executed
private async void ToggleCheckedAsync()
{
    IsBusy = true;
    await DoWork();
    IsBusy = false;
}
```

**As long as one is never calling `ToggleCheckedAsync` directly, are these two scenarios equivalent, or are there any gotchas with one compared to the other?**

(I know `async void` is generally considered a bad practice outside direct event handlers, but `ToggleCheckedAsync` is logically an event handler, and the async lambda in scenario 1 is also AFAIK effectively `async void`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As long as one is never calling ToggleCheckedAsync directly, are these two scenarios equivalent, or are there any gotchas with one compared to the other?

Either one is fine; they're equivalent approaches. `async void` is appropriate here because `ICommand.Execute` is logically an event handler. (And make no mistake: there *is* an `async void` in both approaches: the lambda of the first example becomes `async void`).

However, in my own code, this doesn't hold true:

> As long as one is never calling ToggleCheckedAsync directly

In particular, with unit tests. Unit tests can execute your commands directly, and that includes being able to `await` until they complete, and `ICommand` doesn't satisfy this need.

So, I find it's useful to expose the `async Task` methods. Or, if you want to get fancier, develop an [`IAsyncCommand` type with a `Task ExecuteAsync` method and expose that from the ViewModel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx). Taking that design to its logical conclusion, you can end up with a [full `AsyncCommand` that hides the `async void Execute` as an implementation detail](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async/blob/master/src/Nito.Mvvm.Async/AsyncCommand.cs).